# Updating text to match .length is always one behind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some fitlering being used on my site and I have a text block that I would like updated with the number of active filters so the user can always tell how many are applied even if the filters are closed.

The issue is, my count is always one behind either way. It's taking one more click to get the correct number.

I would assume the number is updating with the CURRENT number as opposed to updating AFTER the click has occured, but I can't wrap my brain around how to restructure to address that.

Here's my code:

```
let countFilter = 0;

function updateFilterCount() {
  let countFilter = $(".is-active").length;
  $(".caps.count").text(countFilter);
  if (countFilter > 0) {
    $(".filtered-text").addClass("active");
    $(".caps.all.active").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".filtered-text.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".caps.all").addClass("active");
  }
}

updateFilterCount();

$(".fltr, .fltr-label, .filter_drawer, .button.ghost.filter__button.active").on(
  "click",
  function () {
    updateFilterCount();
  }
);
```

Comment: How does the `.is-active` class get added to the filters?

Comment: There's no need for the global variable `countFilter`. You're using the local variable in the function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your click event handler seems goes before your filters.
I would try to postpone it with `setTimeout()` first or make sure you filters add 'click' listeners before your counter.
Otherwise you need to know exact the handler's order execution and their events.
I would also use `toggleClass()` and you don't need to specify `.active` in your selector because you assign `active` class to all elements of `.filtered-text` or `.caps.all`.

```
function updateFilterCount() {
  const countFilter = $(".is-active").length;
  $(".caps.count").text(countFilter);
  $(".filtered-text").toggleClass('active', !!countFilter);
  $(".caps.all").toggleClass("active", !countFilter);
}

updateFilterCount();

$(".fltr, .fltr-label, .filter_drawer, .button.ghost.filter__button.active").on(
  "click", () => setTimeout(updateFilterCount)
);
```

Comment: that's impossible.

Comment: @KevinB what exactly?

Comment: given the way the code is written, there is no scenario where the click handler gets called before the first call to updateFilterCount. setTimeout in this case does nothing.

Comment: where exactly you see filters' click handlers? they could be added later

Comment: If that's why the count is behind, then updateFilterCount is being called in the wrong place. It should be called in each of those other locations rather than being handled in a separate event. Wrapping something in a setTimeout is never a good solution.

Comment: the scope of the problem is too small to refactor the whole page to get a perfect result